# Form-to-Mail Multiple File Uploads using One File Input Element (Joomla Component)

Tags: php, file, joomla, upload, joomla3.0

I have installed a joomla component [Form-To-Mail](http://www.joomlacalendars.com/form-to-mail-for-joomla) to a Joomla 3.4.4 Installation.  This is the paid version of the Form-to-Mail component, so I have full features and rights to modify.

Currently - I have everything configured, but I need to have the ability to allow for multiple file uploads using a single file input element.

I believe this is the correct file for the code on the file upload element.  If this doesn't look right - let me know if more information is required in order to modify this Component for multiple file uploads:

```
    $.fbuilder.controls[ 'ffile' ] = function(){};
$.extend( 
    $.fbuilder.controls[ 'ffile' ].prototype, 
    $.fbuilder.controls[ 'ffields' ].prototype,
    {
        title:"Untitled",
        ftype:"ffile",
        required:false,
        size:"medium",
        accept:"",
        upload_size:"",
        show:function()
            {
                return '<div class="fields '+this.csslayout+'" id="field'+this.form_identifier+'-'+this.index+'"><label for="'+this.name+'">'+this.title+''+((this.required)?"<span class='r'>*</span>":"")+'</label><div class="dfield"><input type="file" id="'+this.name+'" name="'+this.name+'" accept="'+this.accept+'" upload_size="'+this.upload_size+'" class="field '+this.size+((this.required)?" required":"")+'" /><span class="uh">'+this.userhelp+'</span></div><div class="clearer"></div></div>';
            },
        after_show:function()
        {
            $.validator.addMethod("upload_size", function(value, element,params) 
            {
              return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size/1024 < params);
            });
        }     
    }         
);
```

Can anyone assist me in enabling this feature into this component?

Answer (score 0):

You should ask Form-To-Mail for the same if its paid extension.

Comment: Mrunal - I did ask the plugin developers directly, and their answer was to just use multiple instances of the file uploader - which is not an option. That's why I posed on here to see if something can be developed to specifically have multiple files selected for a single instance of the plugin.